# Problemas al arrancar una aplicación passenger con express

Tags: express, nginx

Estoy tratando de arrancar una aplicación express con nginx

Ubuntu 16.04
Phusion Passenger 5.0.30
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
node v4.2.6
npm 3.5.2

Pero falla.

El conf file es

```
server {
    listen 3001;
    server_name 207.244.71.80;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/html/webApp/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Node.js app
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file /var/www/html/webApp/app.js;
}
```

package.json

```
package.json 
{
  "name": "boldweb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start_dev": "node ./bin/www dev",
    "start_prod": "node ./bin/www prod",
    "start_prod_destroy": "node ./bin/www prod destroySrc",
    "start": "node ./bin/www prod destroySrc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-bytediff": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.10.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-js-obfuscator": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

El log /var/log/nginx al acceder a la URl es:

> age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for
>   application /var/www/html/webApp: An error occurred while starting the
>   web application: it did not write a startup response in time.   Error
>   ID: 3724c2ce   Error details saved to:
>   /tmp/passenger-error-hvKbiv.html   Message from application: An error
>   occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a
>   startup response in time. Please read this
>   article for more information about this problem.
>
> ### Raw
>   process output:
>
> (empty)
>   age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 6-10] Cannot checkout
>   session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error
>   is 3724c2ce. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.

Si corro la aplicación manualmente, esta arranca bien.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Debes colocar la pregunta en español

Comment: @user3429846 encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta y así poder traducirla. // You may also ask in our English site [SO].

Comment: el problema estaba en el start_up file. la verdad no sabia que habia que publicar las cosas en español. Lo edito y dejo en español entonces. gracias.